# Can .NET 6.0 with Xamarin be used to develop Android Wear 3 apps?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, wear-os, android-wear-3.0

I tried to use Jetbrains Rider IDE to develop a small app for my Android Wear 3 based smartwatch (Samsung Galaxy Watch 5 Pro). But faced several obstacles in this regard.

I started with the Android SDK for version 33. But Rider supports only Version 31 at the moment. No sooner said than done. But then I get some conflicts with de OpenJDK. First started with version 13 than downgraded to version 11.

After this stage, I was able to create a new Wear project. But the available Android libraries for Xamarin seems to be left behind with version 28. And using this with the 31 SDKs seems to be incompatible.

On the official Xamarin / Microsoft website is only a KB article regarding the old Android Wear 2. No word about compatibility or roadmap to Android Wear 3.

I'm open to use Visual Studio for Mac or if really necessary to use Visual Studio 2022 on Windows, if there is more recent support for Android Wear development.

Do you have any experience or know whether Android Wear 3 is somehow supported?

Comment: Xamarin is not compatible with .NET 6, it's based on .NET Standard. You could try .NET MAUI, the successor to Xamarin. You'll need VS 2022 for that.

Comment: Umm, do you only want to develop this on Android Wear?? If so why not go native android?

Comment: @FreakyAli Yes, for a small personal project I'm only targeting Android Wear. I wanted to avoid dealing with Java. I'm proficiency in C# and the .NET ecosystem (despite mobile). And Java is always a nightmare in every sense... Despite lacking knowledge of all the features of the more modern Java versions, is using one of the build systems / package manager such as Maven, Gradle, ... just horrible. Hours of trial and error. But maybe I'll give it a try again ;) Thx

Comment: If not I am sure you can go ahead with .Net for Android and do what you are looking for... Just make sure you are using .Net for android and not Xamarin.Android